# How to get children of route

Tags: angular, angular-router

How can I get children object of the router?

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'parameters',
        component: AsideComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: ParametersComponent },
            { path: 'crypto-accounts', component: ParametersCryptoAccountsComponent },
            { path: 'withdrawal-accounts', component: ParametersWithdrawalAccountsComponent },
            { path: 'add-withdrawal-account', component: ParametersAddWithdrawalAccountComponent }
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

And Component

```
export class AsideComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: Router) {
        let children = this.router... ? // <-----
    }
}
```

I have this.router, how can I get the childrens of current state?

Comment: For what purpose do you need access to these children?

Comment: I need make the aside menu for it, same links

Comment: What information do you need for that?

Comment: links (path) and custom data

Answer (score 1):

You need https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

```
export class AsideComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute) {
        let children = this.router.children
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know why this length is 1? I thought it because I have path "" in children, but length of parent.children is 1 too.

Comment: Thanks for the link, solved as this.activatedRoute.routeConfig.children